# How to make a UICollectionViewCell span entire row?

Tags: ios, xcode7, uistoryboard, uicollectionviewcell

**Context**

- I am trying to create something similar to a `Table view` using `UICollectionView`.
- I am using `Xcode7` and storyboarding.
- The way I do it is that I drag the collection view across the entire controller view.
- And then I drag the entire cell across the row and align it with the right and left boundaries.

**Problem**

- But, when I place a label inside the cell, then it gets displayed correctly only when the device is in a horizontal position.
- When the device is vertical, it gets cut off at the left boundary.

**Question**

How do I ensure that the width of the collection view cell matches that of the container width?

Answer (score 1):

1) Implement the function of cell size and return the collection width:

```
-(CGSize) collectionView: (UICollectionView*) collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*) collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath {
    CGFloat height = 50; //set the wanted height
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width,height);
}
```

2) Reload the collection when the screen size change (i.e. orientation change).

Comment: I would need a custom layout for this, right? Was trying to implement this using the default layout. But, will give this a shot.

Comment: No, this function is delegate of layout but if you will implement it (even if you didn't declared the class as delegate of layout), the collection will call it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not using autolayout. You can achieve this entirely in storyboard or through code.
**Using Storyboard**

1. Add UICollectionView in your UIViewController in storyboard.
2. Drag UICollectionView to fill up in your UIViewController.
3. Add Constraints as shown in image.
   [image]
4. Drag UICollectionView to fill up in UICollectionView.
5. Add UILabel (Or whatever you want to have in cell). Also add constraints in that element.
6. Build and run.

Comment: I have auto layout set. But, I am not able to add any constraints at the CollectionView or the CollectionViewCell level. The red lines are not enabled when I select these elements.  I did add at the UILabel which is a part of the cell. But, it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You don't need to add constraints on UICollectionViewCell. Just add controls (eg. UILabel) in cell and add constraints on those controls not on the cell itself.

Comment: I have added constraints on the UILabel. But, for some reason, it does not seem to work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There are errors in the log. 2015-12-31 09:38:20.364 UICollectionView[3712:459961] the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2015-12-31 09:38:20.365 UICollectionView[3712:459961] the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.

Comment: I recreated the collection view and it seems to work now. Don't know how to explain this, but I created it a little differently this time. First time, I dragged the collection view into the controller and just dropped it in so that the collection view covered the entire controller. This time, I dropped it into the centre and then manually dragged the collection view to cover the entire controller. Not sure how that makes a difference, but, I am seeing the correct behaviour now.

Comment: Thats right, I have explained in my answer that you need to drag and resize collection in storyboard than apply constraints.Well, cheers if it is working.